# What was Poledra's task in the Malloreon?

Tags: the-belgariad, the-malloreon

I've read *The Belgariad* and *The Malloreon*, as well as *Belgarath the Sorcerer* and *Polgara the Sorceress* (several times, in fact).

Most of my questions have been answered, save one: *The Malloreon* in particular focuses on each person having a task, or a set of tasks.

> For example, Zakath's task was to be done after the meeting at Korim. He was to make Angaraks accept Eriond their new God. Liselle's task as the Huntress was to bring down her prey at Ashaba - by killing Harakan with Zith. Silk's task as the Guide was, as always, to guide them. Belgarath's task was to find several important pieces of paper, such as the copy of the Malloreon Gospels at Kell and the mariner's chart at Perivor.

So what is the task of Poledra? I assume it's to do with what she does to Mortdja at the end. My assumption is based on the known facts that she's been trained by UL, and that demons are normally beyond the control of humans without the active help of a God. I'm not sure, though; either it's unclear or I'm being unusually dense.

Answer (score 2):

I found [a timeline](https://kalten.sandwich.net/eddings/timeline.html) online which saved me having to read the whole thing again. In short, Poledra's task is to guard the party against *direct action* by

> Zandramas

She does this at least twice, maybe three times:

- she stops Ce'Nedra

> smothering Geran, while under the influence of [presumably] Zandramas

- she stops

> Zandramas killing Ce'Nedra, at the cave in Karanda where the Sardion used to lie

- she stops

> Zandramas in dragon form from killing the party, at Faldor's-farm-a-like where they meet Eriond's first-disciple-to-be

This role doesn't *quite* match her Prophetic title of 'The Woman Who Watches', of course.

Comment: Maybe someone dropped a word, and it was meant to be "The Woman Who Watches Out." :)

Comment: Watching wouldn't be much good all by itself without any other action. The Woman Who Watches [And Takes Appropriate Action Where Necessary].